# Define #define, including some examples

Tags: c#

What are some examples of how to use `#define` in C#?

```
#define //preprocessor directive
```

What is the purpose of it? Here is an example from Microsoft which I still don't get:

```
// preprocessor_if.cs
#define DEBUG
#define MYTEST
using System;
public class MyClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
#if (DEBUG && !MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
#elif (!DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("MYTEST is defined");
#elif (DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are defined");
#else
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are not defined");
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx

Comment: #define (inside a source file) is not often used. Instead, they are defined globally for the compilation (by a compiler switch for example) to indicate environment/platform/framework etc. etc. The #if construct is then used to take different actions where needed. For example, there are classes available on the full framework that are not available in silverlight, so you may need a conditional import depending on whether you are building for silverlight or not.

Comment: so the word DEBUG is both a keyword and arbitrary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Quote](http://www.dotnetperls.com/define-undef):

> The #define and #undef lines should appear at the very top of a source
>   text file and they can adjust compilation options for the entire file.

and

> In the C# language, the #define line is considered a preprocessing
>   directive. There are some invalid syntaxes for defined symbols; you
>   cannot use a number value as the defined identifier, for example.

and

> The #undef directive ensures that after the textual point in the file,
>   the specified identifier is not defined.

In your example, if `DEBUG` is defined (does not matter what it is as long as it is defined) and MYTEST is not defined, then it will show the message shown.

Otherwise, if `DEBUG` is not defined but MYTEST is defined, then it will show the message shown.

If both are defined then it will show the message shown.

**Bottom-line:**

The point of the defines is to selectively apply compilation options to your program to give it a different program flow. It is a carryover from C and C++.

Answer (score 6):

"Preprocessor" means that the results it generates are done *before* the main processing that the compiler does. One of its main uses is to either include or exclude code from a file *before it is even compiled.*

In the example you see, the preprocessor will first `#define` those two symbols, and then evaluate the different `#if/#elif` statements to figure out which code should actually end up in the file. In this case, both symbols are defined, so only the line saying so will be outputted, and only that code will end up being compiled. If you were to decompile the result, you would only see **one** `Console.WriteLine()` statement, and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

`#define` is a special "before compile" directive in C# (it derives from the old [C preprocessor directives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)) that defines a preprocessor symbol.

Coupled with `#if`, depending on what symbols are defined, the various code will be *effectively commented out*. Because of this, code in non-selected paths doesn't even need to be in a compilable state!

In the example above, the symbols `DEBUG` and `MYTEST` are defined manually at the top (with `#define`), thus the code "looks like" the following when it begins the "normal" compilation phase: (In C# this preprocessing is part of the compiler and not a separate tool that runs first.)

```
// preprocessor_if.cs
//#define DEBUG
//#define MYTEST
using System;
public class MyClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
//#if (DEBUG && !MYTEST)
        //Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
//#elif (!DEBUG && MYTEST)
        //Console.WriteLine("MYTEST is defined");
//#elif (DEBUG && MYTEST)
        Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are defined");
//#else
        //Console.WriteLine("DEBUG and MYTEST are not defined");
//#endif
    }
}
```

The `DEBUG` symbol is normally set automatically, depending on if the project is being built for debugging and other symbols can be set as part of the project itself.

Answer (score 1):

Read about preprocessor directives. I write in C++, so I do not use it the same way as you exactly, but basically these are the things that you define before the statements are executed.

Generally, they can be used two ways.

1. To define something before the first function runs, i.e., you can define the numerical value of pie before calling pie as a variable in your main function.
2. Tells the program what to load in order to execute your program correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by *"define the numerical value of pie before calling pie as a variable"*?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *Last seen more than 8 years ago*. Perhaps somebody can chime in?

Answer (score 0):

A preprocessor directive is something that will be evaluated at compile time. A #define directive is to declare a variable that can be evaluated at compile time.

```
   #if (DEBUG && !MYTEST)
       Console.WriteLine("DEBUG is defined");
   #endif
```

The line above won't be compiled because DEBUG and MYTEST is defined at the start of the file.